# c++ calculator atof no errors but it crashes in the middle line (52)

Tags: c++

im new at c++ and i wanted to make a simple calculator , starts crashing when you gvet to line 52 aprox.
but i got stucked at  converting string to integer
( i used atof) but it doesent want to work
any explenations & fixes are welcome thanks 
P.S. i am new to c++ if you recomend any books or sites to learn i would be happy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float num1;
float num2;
float sum;
string operacija;
char *x;



cout << " enter first num"<< endl;
cin >>num1;
a:
cout << " enter operator"<<endl;
cin >> operacija;
l:
cout << "enter num 2"<<endl;
cin >> num2;




if (operacija=="+"){
    sum = num1 + num2;
}
else if (operacija=="-"){

sum = num1 - num2 ;

}

else if (operacija == "/"){
    sum= num1/num2;
}
else if (operacija=="*"){
sum=num1*num2;
}





cout << sum<< endl;

cin >> x;

if ((x=="+")||(x=="-")||(x=="/")||(x=="*"))
{
    num1 = sum;
    operacija =x;

    goto l;

}




else  {


float f = atof(x);
    num1 =f;
    goto a;

   }


 return 0;
}
```

Comment: `goto l;` `goto a;`   Please no...

Comment: Don't use `goto`. `x` is an uninitialized pointer, and `cin >> x` will probably crash.

Comment: Also, too many blank lines.

Comment: `if you recomend any books or sites to learn i would be happy`  First, you should organize your program in a structured manner.  Jumping around all over the place using `goto` not only makes the code much harder to understand and keep track of, it may make no one want to even look at your code due to it being similar to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756527/what-is-spaghetti-code

Answer (score 1):

This is bad:

```
char* x;
cin >> x;
```

What happens is that `cin` reads a string and stores it in the buffer identified by `x`.  But `x` is uninitialized, it doesn't point anywhere in particular and certainly not to a writable buffer.

All of your `x == '*'` tests are broken too.

What you should do instead is first try to read a number using iostreams, and if that fails, read a string instead.

```
if (!(cin >> f)) {
    cin.clear();
    cin >> operacija;
}
```

Comment: i dont compleatly understand what is iostream but i wil check it out & test it , thank you

Comment: @metalec: C++ has two input/output libraries.  `<iostream>`, which provides `std::cin` and `std::cout`, and also `<stdio.h>` (or `<cstdio>`), which has the input/output functions from the C standard library, such as `printf` and `scanf` and `puts`.  The `atof` function is part of the C standard library, and not even the good part of it.  Everything `atof` does, `strtod` does even better, and it is also a standard function in both C and C++.  But since you seem to know more about `cin`, you should use that and stay away from the C functions.